# Validate request object which is a MutableMap(Map) throw exception if it's value is NULL

Tags: dictionary, validation, java-8, request, mutablemap

I have a **MutableMap(map)** as below in a function, let’s assume we have N no.of entries in it. I need to validate values in the map and throw exception with key if it is a `Null`.  Please provide some suggestions on how to achieve using streams of java -8

```
fun validateRequest (map :  MutableMap<String, Array<String>>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", new ArrayList<>());
map.put("2", new ArrayList<>());
map.put("3", null);
map.put("4", new ArrayList<>());
map.put("5", null);
String s = map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == null).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
if (!s.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("{" + s + "} keys are with null values");
}
```

I have tested this code and it works used JDK 1.8 that was my result

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: {3,5} keys are with null values
```